# How do I wipe data completely?

Tags: security, encryption, cryptography

Let's say for a second that I wanted to implement a one time pad. Assume that I have a secure random number generator and I have created a one time pad with the random numbers. Lets say I want to save this on a USB stick or on some space on my filesystem.

Now I have a script or program that can take a message and encrypt or decrypt the message using the one time pad stored. After it has done this I want to try and destroy the one time pad programmatically.

What would you do? I am aware that simply deleting the files is not enough as the data is still on the disk. Is it sufficient to overwrite the one time pad with 0's or some other day.  Will that make it truly irrecoverable.

Also the pad will need to be read into RAM and some stage to do modular arithmetic. What is the best practice to make sure that the RAM is also no longer recoverable?

Can the one time pad truly be implemented in software. What other factors am I missing in thinking of how to implement a one time pad?

Comment: The biggest problem is not zero-filling. Rather, it is making sure the two sides keep their keys synced even in an event of a crash, connectivity loss, etc.

Comment: It is generally best to explain the downvote so that the question may perhaps be refined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm no expert.  Here are my thoughts.

A one time pad between two parties requires that both parties use the same pad.  For each message exchanged between the parties,
each party will remove one "page" from the pad.
In the case of software,
the "page" is an encryption key.
Since errors can happen you need a few things to make it work:

1. You need a way for the parties to sync up which "page" they are on.  Usually during message exchange both parties just know which page to use (the current page),
   but if they are out of sync,
   they need to decide which page to use.
2. When a pad runs out,
   the parties need to decide that it is time to use the next pad.
   Much like page number,
   they just need a way to signal "use new pad".
3. It seems likely that the parties will need a way to determine that they are using the same pad.
   You probably want a way to do this without burning pages in the pad;
   that seems right,
   but may not be required.
4. deleting the pad (or a page in the pad) is tricky.
   You will have to read up on the classic "how to erase a drive such that the nsa cant recover it" stuff.
   I think this involves repeatedly writing different junk to the same sectors on the disk.
5. Remember to never use the same "page" twice.
   The page for a request is different than the page for the response to the request.

Comment: Actually I think the point 4 is the one I am most interested in. In essence I need to find information on the most up to date and secure ways to delete a pad.

Comment: The multi-pass deletion recommendations are based on very old research.  Disk drives are much denser now days and electron microscopes are no longer sensitive enough to recover overwritten data.  For high level coverage of the topic, see: https://www.anti-forensics.com/disk-wiping-one-pass-is-enough/

That being said, for non-technical business reasons.  It may be useful to be able to say that you use multi-pass deletion in order to make people feel better.

Answer (score 0):

**RAM**

***The physical way***

Turning off your pc will erase it after a small period of time. The RAM will be suspectable to a [cold boot attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_boot_attack) for a couple of seconds/minutes, but then the data will be physically gone.

***The programmatical way***

```
/*C code*/ 

//Ask OS for some ram, the size of our data.
char * SensitiveData = malloc(myDataSize); 

//Copy data from hard drive to the ram memory we
//...just allocated. Implement this function your own way.
load_key_from_hardrive(SensitiveData); 

/*Use key here*/ 

//Now let's overwrite the key:
for (i=0;i<myDataSize;i++)
{
   SensitiveData[i]='\0'; //Fill it with zeros.
}

free (SensitiveData); //Give the memory back to the OS.
```

**Hard drive**

***The physical way***

Saving the key on a usb stick and then physically destroying it will guarantee the removal of the key.

***The programmatical way***

There are a lot of ways. Here is one for Linux: Create a new partition, put the key there. Take note of the partition number, in this example it is `sda2`.

To get rid of the key, zero fill the partition:

```
#Linux bash code
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda2 bs=1M
```

If you prefer filling random data for deniability, use:

```
#Linux bash code
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sda3 bs=1M
```

**Other notes**

Zero filling the ram once is enough. Zero filling a modern hard drive once is probably enough but some do it more than once.

Some operating systems cache disk I/O in RAM, for safety, after wiping your hard drive, you should also resort to *Ram > The physical way*. I might be too paranoid here. I don't have deep knowledge of IO cache, perhaps someone else will edit this section better.

If some other pieces of RAM memory can be used to deduce the key, make sure to zero fill those too in a similar fashion to *Ram > The programmatical way*